# Не отображается фоновое изображение background-image

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не отображается фоновое изображение. Все возможные варианты написания 'img/intro-bg.jpg' были испробованы с добавлением обратных слешей, точек и кавычек. Файл изображения лежит в папке img, которая в свою очередь находится в директории с css-файлом.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&family=Raleway:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>ActiveBox</title>
    </head>

<body> 
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__inner">
            <div class="header__logo">
                <img src="img/ActiveBoxLogo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <nav class="nav">
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Features</a>   
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Works</a>   
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Our Team</a>   
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Downloads</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
    
<div class="intro">
    
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Часть кода в файле style.css

```
.intro {
    height: 750px;
    background-image: url('img/intro-bg.jpg') center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: `center no-repeat` — это точно можно указывать в качестве значения `background-image`?

Comment: а вы попробовали поставить `width: 100%`?

Comment: @wololo конечно же НЕТ! https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-image

Answer (score 0):

```css
.intro {
    height: 750px;
    background-image: url("img/intro-bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант помог)

Answer (score 0):

background-image: url('img/intro-bg.jpg') center (center/cover) no-repeat

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]